# Sign s3 URL in PostgreSQL RDS/Amazon Aurora

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

There is a lot of image files being returned by the DB(Either PostgreSQL RDS/Amazon Aurora). We need to sign the URL. Currently, a user defined function or a view returns the records.

I am looking for a way to sign the S3 URL directly in SQL as a user defined function. Unfortunately, there does not seem to be a way other than using Python language inside a user defined function and python is not supported as a procedural language in PostgreSQL/Aurora.

Does someone know of a way we can sign the URL directly as part of a SQL Query in PostgreSQL RDS/Amazon Aurora?

Comment: I'm curious to know why you want to sign the url on the db instance?

Comment: The file names are stored in the database. I need to loop over the result set again, sign them and send them back.  Postgres will return, say, 50,000 rows. The program will have to walk through the returned JSON, sign them and send them back.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible and I've done this.

First, let's see how AWS SDK does it. In JavaScript AWS SDK, we call `getSignedUrlPromise` to get a signed url.

```js
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';
const s3 = new AWS.S3();
s3.getSignedUrlPromise('getObject', { Bucket, Key, Expires: 60 * 60});
```

Starting from [getSignedUrlPromise](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/3a34cbde457ae382ebf004ae831c5670c6086df5/lib/services/s3.js#L1319), to [getSignedUrl](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/3a34cbde457ae382ebf004ae831c5670c6086df5/lib/services/s3.js#L912), [request.presign](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/3a34cbde457ae382ebf004ae831c5670c6086df5/lib/services/s3.js#L929), [AWS.Signers.Presign().sign](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/master/lib/signers/presign.js#L90) and we can see

```
  sign: function sign(request, expireTime, callback) {
    request.on('build', signedUrlBuilder);
    request.on('sign', signedUrlSigner);
// ...
      return AWS.util.urlFormat(request.httpRequest.endpoint);
  }
```

The signing happens in [signedUrlSigner](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/master/lib/signers/presign.js#L43) for V3

```
function signedUrlSigner(request) {
  var auth = request.httpRequest.headers['Authorization'].split(' ');
  if (auth[0] === 'AWS') {
    auth = auth[1].split(':');
    queryParams['Signature'] = auth.pop();
    queryParams['AWSAccessKeyId'] = auth.join(':');
  }

  endpoint.search = AWS.util.queryParamsToString(queryParams);
}
```

The `Signature` is from `headers['Authorization']`, but where is the `Authorization` set?

It's set in [AWS.Signers.S3.addAuthorization](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/master/lib/signers/s3.js#L63)

```
  addAuthorization: function addAuthorization(credentials, date) {
    var signature = this.sign(credentials.secretAccessKey, this.stringToSign());
    var auth = 'AWS ' + credentials.accessKeyId + ':' + signature;

    this.request.headers['Authorization'] = auth;
  },
```

`sign` function is using sha1 with base64 digest

```
  sign: function sign(secret, string) {
    return AWS.util.crypto.hmac(secret, string, 'base64', 'sha1');
  }
```

And `stringToSign` is a little bit confusing but in my experiment the result is

```js
const stringToSign = `GET\n\n\n${EXPIRES}\n/${BUCKET}/${KEY}`;
```

With the above information, we can easily write a postgres function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION image_s3_signed_url(image_row "Image")
RETURNS TEXT AS $$
DECLARE
    newline text := E'\n';
    method text := 'GET';
    bucket text := 'my_bucket';
    access_key text := 'my_access_key';
    access_secret text := 'my_access_secret';
    filepath text;
    expires bigint;
    tosign text;
    raw_signature text;
    encoded_signatre text;
    result text;
BEGIN

  filepath := image_row.filepath;
  expires = EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) + 60 * 60;
  
  tosign := method || newline || newline || newline || expires || newline || '/' || bucket || filepath;
  raw_signature := encode(hmac(tosign, access_secret, 'sha1'), 'base64');
  -- encodeURIComponent:
  encoded_signatre := REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(raw_signature, '+', '%2B'), '/', '%2F'), '=', '%3D');

  result = filepath || '?AWSAccessKeyId=' || access_key || '&Expires=' || expires || '&Signature=' || encoded_signatre;

  RETURN result;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE;
```

The result is

```
/KEY?AWSAccessKeyId=my_access_key&Expires=EXPIRES&Signature=signature
```

and adding your s3 host `https://my_bucket.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com` in frontend to be

```
https://my_bucket.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/KEY?AWSAccessKeyId=my_access_key&Expires=EXPIRES&Signature=signature
```

Answer (score -1):

Database is not the place to perform such operation.
You should consider either putting a signed URL into the database already or to rethink your application if it shouldn't be rearchitected.

Comment: You should never persist signed URL in the db.

Comment: The idea behind the question is to return signed URL from the db